# Using desktop-file-install in RPM

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

When using desktop-file-install, where I'm expected to place .desktop file? I have read the documentation but nothing mentioned about the path.

Comment: Do you need to specify a directory? Does it not default to the correct location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `desktop-file-install` [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/desktop-file-install.1.html) appears to indicate that without passing a directory at all the defaults will do what you want.

> RPM_BUILD_ROOT
>
> This variable is set when building RPM packages.  If the `--dir`
>        option and the **DESKTOP_FILE_INSTALL_DIR** environment variable are
>        not used, it will automatically  be  prepended  to  the  default
>        install  directory  to  install  the desktop files appropriately
>        when building packages.